# Adding style to a dynamically created back div

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are dynamically created div blocks, via JS, into which data from an array of products is written, it is necessary to check, and if stock = no, then the div in which it is located should turn gray. I only managed to make all the blocks gray, please fix the error in the code

```
<script>
    const goods = [
        {
            img: "/img/iphone.jpg",
            name: 'iphone',
            model: 'Gky-42-s',
            stock: 'yes'
        },
        {
            name: 'Samsung',
            model: 'JIj-21s',
            stock: 'yes'
        },
        {
            name: 'Honor',
            model: 'Jiu-21-e-2',
            stock: 'no'
        },
    ]

    let wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
    class Card {
        render() {
            let htmlCard = '';
            goods.forEach(({name, model, stock, img}) => {
                htmlCard += `
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="${img}">
                    <span>${name}</span>
                    <span>${model}</span>
                    <span>${stoak}</span>
                </div>`
            });
            wrapper.innerHTML = htmlCard

            let div = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

            for (let i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
                goods.forEach(({stock}) => {
                    if (stock=== 'нет') {
                        div[i].classList.add('gray')
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    let CardStoak = new Card();
    CardStoak.render();
</script>
```

Comment: Only  `<span>${stoak}</span>` to `<span>${stock}</span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert this line:

```
<span>${stoak}</span>
```

To this:

```
<span>${stock}</span>
```

And you can do this in one loop

```js
goods.forEach(({name, model, stock, img}) => {
    var classes = (stock==="нет")? "card gray": "card";
    htmlCard += `
    <div class="${classes}"">
        <img src="${img}">
        <span>${name}</span>
        <span>${model}</span>
        <span>${stock}</span>
    </div>`
});
```

And remove this:

```
let div = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

for (let i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    goods.forEach(({stock}) => {
        if (stock=== 'нет') {
            div[i].classList.add('gray')
        }
    });
}
```